# Hibernate search 6 , refresh index after updating entity

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-search-6

I didn't find unfortunatly a solution for my Problem and I need help.
I have tow entity like that

```
@Table(name = "A")
@Entity
@Indexed
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EntityA {

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private EntityB b;
}


@Table(name = "B")
@Entity
@Indexed
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EntityB {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "b")
    private EntityA a;
    
    @KeywordField(name = "text_sort", sortable = Sortable.YES)
    @FullTextField(projectable = Projectable.YES)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String text;

}
```

I make a first save for my EntityA

```
EntityB entityB = new EntityB();
entityB.setText("text");
EntityA entityA = new EntityA();
entityA.setB(entityB);
entityARespository.save(entityA);
```

then I want to update the field text in the entityB, so I get first the entityA from the database and then make the update and save the entityA

```
EntityA entityA = entityARepository.findById(1L);
entityA.getB().setText("test")
entityBRepository.save(entityA);
```

then when I make a research with the string "test" and don't find any result, but with string "text" yes . That's mean the index ist not refreshed but I didn't find where the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible explanations:

1. Your update to the value `test` is done outside of a transaction. Make sure to use a transaction, or if you really don't want one, call `entityManager.flush()` (`entityBRepository.flush()` with Spring Data, I suppose?) after the call to `save()`.
2. You didn't wait long enough for the update to be visible. Elasticsearch is a near-real-time platform. This means your updates are not visible immediately, but after a periodic "refresh", which happens every second by default.

   See [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#concepts-commit-refresh) for more information about the concept of "refresh".

   You can configure Hibernate Search to force a refresh after each index update by using the [`sync` synchronization strategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexing-automatic-synchronization), but then Elasticsearch's performance will be poor. I would only recommend that for automated tests, definitely not in production.

Comment: I change it with saveAndFlush() but still the same problem.
I am using lucene backend here are my configurations:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.backend.directory.type=local-filesystem
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.backend.directory.root=C://Search
I kept the other config as a default

Comment: I added this two configs:spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.search.backend.io.writer.infostream= true
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.search.backend.lucene.infostream= TRACE, but I can't find the log after making a search test?!

Comment: `spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.search.backend.lucene.infostream= TRACE` is incorrect. You need to set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.backend.io.writer.infostream=true`and *also* set the logging level for `org.hibernate.search.backend.lucene.infostream` to `TRACE`, as explained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-lucene-io-writer). In spring boot you'd set the logging level through `logging.level.org.hibernate.search.backend.lucene.infostream=TRACE`.

Comment: Though in your case I would rather expect the problem to come from how you perform your changes with ORM, rather than from Lucene. Please show us the *full* code used to make the updates, including any context like the service class, the test class and all their methods.

Comment: yes you areright, I have fixed a problem of persistence caused by my project architecture and now it works, your the best thank you

Comment: for spring-data-jpa is unfortunatly still not working for me, I mean if I have an object that have already an Id I want to update it , I don't need do call find , I can directly call save methode and spring-data-jpa will take care of every thing in the background

Comment: I don't know which method you are talking about. Like I said above, if you want help, you need to show the full code. Something that allows someone else to reproduce your problem independently.